# Two columns outside matrix

Tags: bordermatrix

I have a matrix with elements outside of this matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bordermatrix{     
            & A_1     & A_2     & \cdots & A_n      \cr
    C_1     & w_1     & w_2     & \ldots & w_1      \cr
    C_2     & w_2     & w_2     & \ldots & w_2      \cr
    \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots   \cr
    C_n     & w_n     & w_n     & \ldots & w_n      \cr
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to add a second column, let say B_1, B2,..., B_n, to the left of the C column. 
How to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert a `matrix` environment ahead of the existing `\bordermatrix{...}` material.

[image]

Feel free to fine-tune the horizontal separation between the two matrices to your liking. (I inserted a thinspace -- `\,` -- but you may prefer either more or less separation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix} 
   B_1 \\ B_2 \\ \vdots \\ B_n 
\end{matrix}\,
\bordermatrix{     
            & A_1     & A_2     & \cdots & A_n      \cr
    C_1     & w_1     & w_2     & \ldots & w_1      \cr
    C_2     & w_2     & w_2     & \ldots & w_2      \cr
    \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots   \cr
    C_n     & w_n     & w_n     & \ldots & w_n      \cr
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You also can use the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\usepackage{blkarray, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{cc>{\:}cccc<{\:}}
 & & A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_n \\
\begin{block}{c@{\:}c <{\!}(>{\:}cccc<{\:})}
B_1 & C_1 & w_1 & w_2 & \ldots & \Gape[1.5ex][0pt]{w_1} \\
B_2 & C_2 & w_2 & w_2 & \ldots & w_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
B_n & C_n & w_n & w_n & \ldots &\Gape[0pt][1.5ex]{ w_n}\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{NiceMatrix}
   & & A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_n \\
  B_1 & C_1 & w_1 & w_2 & \ldots & w_1 \\
  B_2 & C_2 & w_2 & w_2 & \ldots & w_2 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  B_n & C_n & w_n & w_n & \ldots & w_n 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-3}{5-6})
\end{NiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]